# Ubuntu Server running Pi-Hole unable to resolve host: no address associated with host name

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp

I recently turned a recycled 2012 Macbook pro into a recursive DNS. I installed Ubuntu server 20.04.2 onto the machine and am using Pi-Hole, which is used to block the ip address of ads on most websites. I was not interested in this functionality, but was interested in using it as a recursive DNS server, which can be done by doing some reconfiguring. The issue I am having, is that my Ubuntu server does not seem to be able to access the internet. I ran the command `sudo apt update` to try and update the app repository, I think that is the correct term. It seems to return a series of errors regarding "failure to fetch" archive files due to being unable to resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com.'

How can I fix this issue. I am having a great time with playing around with all of this, and am really enjoying having my own custom DNS server. I have read some people have success with allowing the Pi-Hole to do **DHCP**. I tried it, and did not get any success. does anyone have any other suggestions regarding this situation? Am I worried for nothing? Any help would be great.

---

Edit:

I was able to find a bit of a work around. By pointing my Linux Server to an outside DNS, I can use that for update and such, while still using the Pi-Hole as the Recursive DNS for the rest of my network. This is the method I used:
https://www.ricmedia.com/set-permanent-dns-nameservers-ubuntu-debian-resolv-conf/

I would like to figure out how to fix this entirely if possible.

Comment: So I have  a Pi-Hole server, that points to my Bind9 DNS server, which hosts my local domain, and is configured to forward unknown domain queries up to the DNS servers I've deemed best for my network. Where does your Pi-Hole server point?

Comment: My Pi-Hole points to itself as the Recursive DNS using a different port than the ad filtering. It also points to my router as the default gateway. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: So Pi-Hole needs a server to forward unresolved queries to (those not on the blocklist). see the install documentation here: https://docs.pi-hole.net/guides/dns/unbound/ where they forward to a Unbound DNS server. you could forward to any DNS server of your choice, like opendns, or google or whatever. the pihole server will handle the queries recursively, in that the client will get a single response to complex queries like a.b.c.d.e.f.g.com.